# grep never exiting when it should be searching through a small tempfile

Tags: linux, bash, mktemp

I have a problem with mktemp and grep.

```
OUT=$(mktemp /tmp/output.XXXXXXXXXX) || { echo "Failed to create temp file"; exit 1; }
awk -F: '{print $7}' /etc/passwd >> $OUT
grep -c $1 $OUT
```

In grep line, code not exits, not prints value of grep
Please, help me to solve that problem.

Comment: What does `$1` contain when it is hanging. No matter what it contains, try quoting it as `"$1"`

Comment: $1 contains bash

Comment: I suspect that `$1` might be empty , which makes the last command `grep -c $OUT`. Calling `grep` with a single argument makes it wait for the second argument indefinitely. Can you debug and check what `$1` actually contains?

Comment: s/wait for the second argument/wait for text on stdin/ (but otherwise, spot-on).

Comment: @John, please prove that (specifically, the expansion of `$1` having the value you expect) to us. Providing a transcript of your script running with `set -x` to enable debug logging would work, f/e. (That is to say, make the very first line the command `set -x`, and [edit] the output that generates into the question).

Answer (score 0):

BlackPearl above probably is correct - `$1` likely is empty during your program execution.  As a result, the grep command looks like this:  `grep -c $OUT` which tells grep to look for `$OUT` in the stdin.  stdin is the keyboard (I suspect) so grep will wait forever (well, until you press Ctrl-D or Ctrl-C).

To solve your problem, specify a parameter when you execute your script.

You can also avoid the problem entirely by counting all of the unique values in your passwd file like this:

```
OUT=$(mktemp /tmp/output.XXXXXXXXXX) || { echo "Failed to create temp file"; exit 1; }
awk -F: '{print $7}' /etc/passwd >> "$OUT"
sort "$OUT" | uniq -c  # count each unique value in passwd file column 7
```

Comment: If trying to show best-practice code, you should really be quoting expansions. If you don't control `IFS`, even the output from `mktemp` can be split in surprising ways when later used in an unquoted expansion (consider if `IFS=/`).

Comment: Modified code to quote expansions as suggested by @CharlesDuffy.